# Does it make sense an inertial mass dipole moment for massless particles?

Tags: inertia, multipole-expansion, dipole-moment

Electric and magnetic dipoles exist in nature even with zero net electric and magnetic charge

Electrons have a unit of charge, about $10^{-31}$ kg of inertial mass, zero electric dipole moment, $\hbar / 2$ magnetic dipole moment.

As far as we know, there are no negative masses in nature, and there seems to be good reasons for that. But I'm curious if the concept of an inertial dipole mass moment can be expressed rigurously in quantum or classical physics in a way that would allow one to design experiments to test it

The question can be summarized like this: If it makes sense for a particle to have either a charge or a charge dipole, why would not make sense to ask for the presence of a mass dipole?

Comment: lurscher, I hoped to see an answer and by this to get what you ask really. Perhaps it's time to edit the question?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler electrons have a unit of charge, about $10^{31}$ kg of inertial mass, zero electric dipole moment, $\hbar /2$ magnetic dipole moment. The question can be summarized like this:  If it makes sense for a particle to have either a charge or a charge dipole, why would not make sense to ask for the presence of a mass dipole?